# offlineimap + procmail/sieve + mutt

Tags: mutt

I already have offlineimap + mutt properly set up, but I am subscribed to lots of mailing lists that I don't know how to sort to their proper folder. I do it manually from mutt by filtering them by pattern (Shift + T and then ;s to save them to the proper location), but I understand there's a way to do this automatically with procmail or sieve, but I couldn't find anything. Is there a way procmail can be integrated with offlineimap as a postsynchook ?

Answer (score 3):

I am looking at the same thing currently and I found one guy who does it like that:

1. Run a Dovecot server locally
2. Synchronise it with his Gmail account with mbsync (OfflineIMAP alternative)
3. Uses sieve localy on Dovecot created version
4. Read the local IMAP server via the builtin mutt functionality

Link to his repo: https://github.com/dabrahams/feedme

He's running it on a Mac, but I guess it should work on Linux too. I hope that helps at least a bit.

Comment: I solved the problem by using imapfilter, where you can filter messages (I just need to filter by the To: and Cc: fields) and sort them in local mailboxes. Then, you just add those mailboxes to your .muttrc to be displayed by mutt.